# Client-server opc ua in C#

Tags: c#, client-server, opc, opc-ua

I have to write a client-server application in C# using OPC UA API. Where I can find a simple example or a simple guide? I have seen Test Applications but it is so complex. Thank you.

Comment: The duplicate is an answer for OPC DA development. This question is about OPC UA.

Comment: You should look for the Quick Start Applications in the OPC Foundation download area http://opcfoundation.org/DownloadFile.aspx?CM=3&RI=911&CN=KEY&CI=285&CU=1. Unified Automation has also released a preview of their upcoming SDK for .NET, http://www.unified-automation.com/

Comment: Unified Automation SDK for .net allows to use the same service of OPC SDK?

Comment: They are rewriting the API based on the OPC Foundation SDK. It will be an improved version of the OPC Foundation SDK.